# JBehave incorrectly identifying two steps that have a similar step text part

Tags: bdd, jbehave, jbehave-plugin, jbehave-maven-plugin

```
sign out as \"$signOutUser\"

sign out as \"$signOutUser\" and sign in as \"$signInUser\"
```

Above are the two step definitions that cause this issue. JBehave misreads the below step.

```
When sign out as "userA" and sign in as "userB"
```

Even though the corresponding step should be interpreted to the 2nd step definition, it incorrectly interprets to 1st steps as,

```
When sign out as 'userA" and sign in as "userB'
```

I'm using JBehave 4.0.5. Is this a recognized issue? Or newer version has a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps with similar syntax must be [prioritized](https://jbehave.org/reference/latest/prioritising-steps.html):

```java
@When(value="sign out as \"$signOutUser\"")
@When(value="sign out as \"$signOutUser\" and sign in as \"$signInUser\"", priority=1)
```

Comment: Spot on. I missed this in the documentation.